# Error while installing COMSOL on amazon AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, cloud

I was trying to run COMSOL on Amazon AWS.

While file following the link [RunningCOMSOLOnTheAmazonCloud.pdf](http://www.comsol.com/shared/downloads/RunningCOMSOLOnTheAmazonCloud.pdf), 
I face errors when trying to install COMSOL on the AMI. When I try to install COMSOL into the remote terminal: `cd ~/Private/comsol/COMSOL43b_dvd/setup ami`, I get this error:

```
bash: cd: /root/Private/comsol/COMSOL43b_dvd/setup: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be caused by you trying to navigate to a non existing directory

Please check that the directory exists

```
ls /root/Private/comsol/COMSOL43b_dvd/
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're at part 2 on page 25 of [this document](http://www.comsol.com/shared/downloads/RunningCOMSOLOnTheAmazonCloud.pdf). The instructions there are not very well worded but I think I can see what's going wrong:

---

**2** Install COMSOL:

```
cd ~/Private
/comsol/COMSOL43b_dvd/setup ami
```

Answer the following questions:

- Enter the installation directory: (press enter for default:
  /home/ec2-user/Private/)
- Accept the license agreement (press the space bar to flip the pages until the last
  one, and answer yes to the question if you agree).
- Enter the path to the license file: (press enter for default: 1718@localhost)

---

The tilde (`~`) is a shorthand for any user's `home` directory. This is usually in the form `/home/user`. If you are logged in as the root user, then the home directory is `/root`. It looks like you are still the root user, when you should be `ec2-user`, which is Amazon's default username for most of their Linux EC2 instances. (The suggested default installation directory of `/home/ec2-user/Private` is what makes me think that)

Try running `su - ec2-user` to change to the right user, then type `pwd` to get the console to print out the directory you're in. You should be in the home directory.

Use the `ls` command to list all the contents of the directory you are in, or `ls -l` to give you a more detailed list.

You can also use the `tab` button on your keyboard to autocomplete filenames if they exist. Pressing `tab` twice will give you a list of options. If pressing `tab` doesn't complete, or show a list of options after a double tap, then the directory does not exist.